# Can't use $translate.use in app.run: undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

since I upgraded angular-translate from 2.9.0 to 2.15.2 I can't use the $translate.use() function anymore in my rootScope (app.run)

The value of $translate.use() is undefined, while loading the page. This is the code what I use to load the language and to change the language.

```
$rootScope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    if(langKey.length == 2) {
        $translate.use(langKey.toLowerCase()+"_"+langKey.toUpperCase());
        $rootScope.language = langKey;
    } else if(langKey.length == 5) {
        $translate.use(langKey);
        $rootScope.language = langKey.substring(0,2);
    }
};

$rootScope.changeLanguage($translate.use());
```

This code gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at m.e.changeLanguage (app.js:184)

(minified code, so $rootScope is renamed to m.e.)

This log line gives me the following:

```
console.log("trans", $translate.versionInfo(), $translate.use());
```

> trans 2.15.2 undefined

How can I get this working again?

Comment: Share your complete console error

Comment: @VicJordan added some extra code

Comment: [The documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate#methods_use) says: *If no or a falsy key is given it returns the currently used language key. The returned string will be undefined if setting up $translate hasn't finished.* You probably need to use onReady().

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, I read that, but in the previous version it was working fine on that specific place

Comment: @NVO, just in case, are you properly injecting $translate in required controller?

Comment: Yep, `myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$window', '$location', '$stateParams', '$api', '$translate', '$transitions', '$state',
 function($rootScope, $window, $location, $stateParams, $api, $translate, $transitions, $state) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting this error because when script is running first time at that time langKey is undefined, so add check inside the changeLanguage function before using langKey like below. It will work:

```
    $rootScope.changeLanguage = function(langKey) {
      if (langKey) {
        if (langKey.length == 2) {
          $translate.use(langKey.toLowerCase() + "_" + langKey.toUpperCase());
          $rootScope.language = langKey;
        } else if (langKey.length == 5) {
          $translate.use(langKey);
          $rootScope.language = langKey.substring(0, 2);
        }
      }
    };

    $rootScope.changeLanguage($translate.use());
```

Comment: Ah, very simple, I should have tgat myself too, but, it worked!